# redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my `users_controller` method. it should be redirected if user is not activated.

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?
end
```

Here I dont understand the need of return in the method as it would happen automatically before the redirect_to is executed. I have seen many example but most of them have more if statements, so return skips those checks. Here, is it necessary?

Comment: It makes no sense here.

Comment: Do You use `Devise`?

Comment: Its from railstutorial book written by Michael Hartl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return statement makes no sense here. You can just write

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless @user.activated?
end
```

The return statement is sometimes uses as a trick to avoid the double rendering issue, especially with explicit `render`. Take this example:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(some_url) unless @user.activated?
  redirect_to(other_url) unless @user.other?
  render action: "hello"
end
```

If you don't use the return here, when the method returns there is a chance that you defined a rendering behavior twice or even three times.

Generally speaking, multiple rendering with returns is a sign of coding smell. You can often refactor the action to properly use before actions that are designed to stop the execution chain if any of the action set a rendering behavior.

Comment: So, wrote `user32175`  about needing to use non-standard render action? No. Therefore using standard default features of `Devise` is sufficient!

Comment: @СергійНазаревич The user didn't mention Devise at all. There is no need to use Devise here.

Answer (score -1):

If You use `Devise`, You could write:

```
  # GET /users/:id.:format
  def show
    # authorize! :read, @user
  end
```

It is workable as default.

**Update**. Pay attention: If You have to enable activation via email, You could write:

In device.rb (find this strings and uncomment it):

```
  # ==> Configuration for :confirmable
  # A period that the user is allowed to access the website even without
  # confirming his account. For instance, if set to 2.days, the user will be
  # able to access the website for two days without confirming his account,
  # access will be blocked just in the third day. Default is 0.days, meaning
  # the user cannot access the website without confirming his account.
  config.confirm_within = 2.days

  # Defines which key will be used when confirming an account
  config.confirmation_keys = [ :email ]
```

And in User Model (add into `device string`):

```
device ..., :comfirmable
```

Comment: How on the Earth this is connected to what OP has asked?

Comment: In part before `update` answere is -- `He don't has to write something such as he does not have any non-standard requirements`. In part `update` I clarified ’If he has to do activation via email and If he has to check user activation, He should do this around Devise, turn on this in Devise's settings'  ---- It is wrong? In many my projects it is workable...