# Weird logical construction in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm working on Michael Hartl "Ruby on Rails Tutorial" and encountered the following code:

```
redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?
```

Please explain why `return` was included into this code. I tested `redirect_to root_url unless @user.activated?` and it works without `return`. Am I missing something?

The full code of users_controller.rb:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find_by id: params[:id]
    redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated? 
  end
```

Please also explain using `and` in the same line. The book gives the following explanation about `and`, but it is still unclear to me.

> Note that Listing 11.40 uses and in place of &&. The two are nearly
>   identical, but the latter operator has a higher precedence, which
>   binds too tightly to root_url in this case. We could fix the problem
>   by putting root_url in parentheses, but the idiomatically correct way
>   to do it is to use and instead.

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265863/redirect-to-root-url-and-return-unless-user-activated

Comment: The linked question answer your first question. Your second question can be answered by looking at the implicit parenthesis between `redirect_to(root_url) and return unless @user.activated?` vs. `redirect_to(root_url && return) unless @user.activated?`. In the second case, the redirect would not get executed since the function is ended before the `redirect_to` method is even called.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand this.